# missing a command during running alien to convert a .rpm - .deb

Tags: deb, rpm, alien

[image: This is what i am confused on how to take it to the next step.]

I need to generate this .rpm file with alien to .deb and then i need to sudo dpkg -i the.deb file

But in terminal it does not show me it has converted it.

Im sure its a small command that im not aware of please enlighten me

Comment: First, you should use Alien as a last resort, you are better off compiling from source. Second, your command is off, you have two -- in front of the .rpm `sudo alien your.rpm`, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use Alien as a last resort, you are better off compiling from source.

Second, your command is off, you have two -- in front of the .rpm, use  `sudo alien your.rpm`

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto for details